# Bitbucket cannot load google cloud key file

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket doesn't read my base64 encoded json file with Google cloud service key.
I have successfully encoded and then decoded the same file myself, that Bitbucket tries to decode.
But Bitbucket fails to do it with `base64: invalid input` error.
Here is the full error message:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/google-app-engine-deploy:0.6.1
INFO: Setting up environment.
echo "${KEY_FILE}" | base64 -d >> /tmp/key-file.json
base64: invalid input
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/key-file.json --quiet --verbosity=warning
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Could not read json file /tmp/key-file.json: Unterminated string starting at: line 3 column 17 (char 49)
gcloud config set project wowzers --quiet --verbosity=warning
Updated property [core/project].
INFO: Starting deployment to GCP app engine...
gcloud app --quiet deploy app.yaml --version=14 --promote --stop-previous-version --verbosity=debug --quiet --verbosity=warning
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not currently have an active account selected.
```

As I understand it fails here, on `"project_id": "`. 
Decoded file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-318",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  ...
}
```

I have tried to feed my base64 encoded key file firstly through environment variable and then through file. But with the same error. When it cannot extract JSON bitbucket writes this error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Could not read json file /tmp/key-file.json: No JSON object could be decoded`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the key file from google cloud contains newline symbols: `\n`.
So result base64 encoded file also looked like this:

```
HhsUUrAkupWJ6vdesSRHwNhnPpgxByYT7z7HVBEPsrUpjLWdX6TQm4pHNJydsC34F
RvVYyBAedgLhWPPGPvU6UBJww3aNxQnJS95ZvKDBuNr5CNTtAgh6EgsattRrZtawH
fjphVs82UWZZFq3JUeGwGdTs88XWu6ejaPYZknnD94W7pU6Ds8vJHGhAnBw9FtkrA
gjp4UFZN2Yg9KJFSrTfFA6dUsp2dPVN6VzVfpqJzGrxbFBjWQAp4zK5TXhJaN4zDr
.....
```

But in order to pass it to Bitbucket you need to have it all in one line:

```
HhsUUrAkupWJ6vdesSRHwNhnPpgxByYT7z7HVBEPsrUpjLWdX6TQm4pHNJydsC34FRvVYyBAedgLhWPPGPvU6UBJww3aNxQnJS95ZvKDBuNr5CNTtAgh6EgsattRrZtawHfjphVs82UWZZFq3JUeGwGdTs88XWu6ejaPYZknnD94W7pU6Ds8vJHGhAnBw9FtkrAgjp4UFZN2Yg9KJFSrTfFA6dUsp2dPVN6VzVfpqJzGrxbFBjWQAp4zK5TXhJaN4zDr....
```

After I manually removed new line symbols it gave success message:
`Activated service account credentials for: [project]`

Comment: When I was copying/pasting from bash it was also adding new lines. I used the command `base64 key.json > base64-key.tmp` then used the string inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to use GCP's KMS (Key Management Service).. It is so easy to decrypt base 64 and Under KMS you will need to have the appropriate user role to decrypt it accordingly. Steps to use KMS is code snippet below:

```
KEYRING=kubernetes-secrets
KEY=generic-type-encryption-key

gcloud kms keyrings create $KEYRING --location asia-east2
gcloud kms keys create $KEY --location asia-east2 \
                            --keyring $KEYRING \
                            --purpose encryption

gcloud kms encrypt --location asia-east2 \
                       --keyring $KEYRING \
                       --key $KEY \
                       --plaintext-file example.txt \
                       --ciphertext-file encrypted.example.txt
```

Comment: Can you clarify how one authenticates to use the KMS? It sems to me that in order to authenticate to the KMS within a bitbucket build pipeline you would need to pass in a service account key, which would require the same passing of the key that is already the problem to OP has.

Comment: Yes you will need a service account to get access to Google APIs in general. In CircleCI I just pass the service account JSON as an environment variable since the environment variables are displayed as "*" in CircleCI UI

Comment: So you need to pass the json key file to use the KMS, and the OP problem was in passing the key file. As such I don't think KMS is a useful solution here - being able to use the KMS would allow the OP to use the app engine deploy pipeline directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using OS X

1. Recommend dowload the JSON Service Account File

after that you will convert the file to base64

```
openssl base64 -A -in <ServiceAccountPrivateKey.json>   -out <newfile.txt>
```

-A: Will put on one line the result .

You can past the result to your repository variable